# attach security group created in another app

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7FvL.png).

I am creating the following for 2 seperate applications using same modules in terragrunt

- LB
- Instances
- Security Groups

my question is how do I reference a security group created for app1 in app2?

eg.

in app1 
I can references it as 
security_groups    =  ["${aws_security_group.sec_group_A.id}"]
how can I refer the same security group in app2?

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sec_group_A" { 
  name   =   "sec_group_A"
  ...
  ...
  }

resource "aws_elb" "bar" {
  name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
  security_groups    =  ["${aws_security_group.sec_group_A.id}"]
  ...
  ...
  }
```

Comment: Are App1 and App2 are in separate modules?

Comment: Do you `apply` out the changes to both app1 and app2 at the same time?

Comment: app1 and app2 are using same module

Comment: I apply changes at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app2, you can:

```
data "aws_security_group" "other" {
    name = "sec_group_A"
}
```

and then use the ID:

```
resource "aws_elb" "bar" {
    name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
    security_groups    =  ["${data.aws_security_group.other.id}"]
    ...
    ...
}
```

(caveat for using `data` is that you are running two separate `terraform apply`s - one configuration creates the group, and other configuration references the group).

Comment: this would give me the id for security group created in app2

Comment: EH - no... the group created in app A is called "sec_group_A" and presumably has an app specific unique name. Using the `data` item, you find it by name and use it's id in your ELB declaration in the second configuration

Comment: that worked thanx, another related question,how can I create that resource first i.e. if app2 is using a secgroup created in app1 how can I tell terraform to build app1 first and then app2

Comment: In that case you are using the wrong strategy: you need a single configuration that creates both apps and you let terraform figure out the dependency graph.  I personally have moved away from those mega-configs, perfering to limit the "blast radius" of an individual config and let each config manage smaller amounts.  I go old school and number my folders (10-Groups\; 15-AppA\; 20-AppB\). Any other scripting tech can iterate over the folders if I need

Comment: can you please give an example of what you think I should do and also how you do it as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of using terragrunt, but normally I would be calling my modules from a "main.tf" file in the root of the project. An example folder structure is below

```
.
├── main.tf
└── modules
    ├── app1
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    └── app2
        ├── main.tf
        ├── outputs.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

My app1 outputs.tf declares a security group A output

```
output "sec_group_a" { value = "${aws_security_group.sec_group_A}" }
```

I can then call this output in my main.tf file in the root of the project. This would look something like the below

```
module "app1" {
  source = "./modules/app1"
  ...
  // Pass in my variables
}

module "app2" {
  source = "./modules/app2"
  sec_group_A = "${module.app1.sec_group_A}"
  ...
  //Pass in the rest of my variables
}
```

Finally inside of the app2 module you can call this as you would any other variable.

```
resource "aws_elb" "bar" {
  name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
  security_groups    =  ["${var.sec_group_A.id}"]
  ...
  ...
  }
```

I'd read up on modules here https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html to get a better understanding of how they fit together.

Alternatively you can grab the data from your remote state (if you have one configured) as long as sec_group_A declared as an output in app1. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html